# What files get modified by the authconfig?

Tags: linux, ldap, authentication, centos6, openldap

I am trying to identify which files are edited with the following command, but can not find.

```
authconfig --enablemd5 --enableshadow --enablecache --enablelocauthorize --enableldap --enableldapauth --ldapserver = ldap: //test-01.com --ldapbasedn = "dc = teste, dc = com, dc = us" - -enablemkhomedir -update
```

I can only configure ldap to the authconfig command.
I need to do manually editing the files.

Comment: A quick and dirty method would be to run a `find -mtime 0` after running that command on a base install

Comment: We used etckeeper for this exact purpose

Answer (score 0):

If your system is using PAM as the underlying authentication provider according to the documentation the options you specified with `authconfig` will modify the required PAM files(similar to using `pam-config`) which should be located in `/etc/pam.d`(at least on openSUSE, where there is no auth).

It also appears that it will modify `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.  You should also be able to check if `sssd` is enabled.  In addition `/etc/ldap.conf` may need to be updated.